# Dynamic Dropdown Div Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need a snippet of code for creating an "other" dropdown option.  Basically, if there are 3 options for color: red|green|blue, I want them to have the ability to select other and when selected a div appears with a textbox for them to enter the next color.  Posting code now....sorry people.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<label class="desc">
                                    Operating System:
                                </label>
                                <div><select name="os" id="os"><option value="1" selected = "selected">Windows 98</option>
```

Windows ME
Create New

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#os').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'other')
      $('#otheros').show();
    else
      $('#otheros').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you really need to try something rather than just ask us to do the work for you .... please edit your question to include the code you have tried and were it is going wrong

Comment: I did try and it didn't work.  I've googled but haven't found anything that will work so I asked the experts...  I need this to work with jquery.  Found something in javascript that was similar, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: why did the code show up like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a code snippet and here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FyPKg/5/)

```
#otherOption
{
    display:none;
    margin-left:5px;
}

<select id='ddlColors'>
    <option value = 'red'>red</option>
    <option value = 'blue'>blue</option>
    <option value = 'other'>other</option>
</select>
<div id='otherOption'>
    <input type='text' />
</div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddlColors').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'other')
            $('#otherOption').show();
        else
            $('#otherOption').hide();
    });
});​
```

Comment: that's extremely close to what I was trying.  But I still can't get it to work.  Sorry didn't realize I needed to post code, but I will do it now

Comment: so you are saying that the example is not working ?!

Comment: it was my div that caused the problem, not your code.